# Opening a boostrap modal after closing another - unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a bootstrap modal immediately after user close another. So I use the following code trying to do this:

```
currentModal.modal('hide').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (){
    nextModal.modal('show');
});
```

Everything happens normally. First modal closes and next modal appears.

However, the `class="modal-open"` should be in `body` element to scroll works properly, what is not happening. After second modal is shown, that class disappears from `body`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I doing something wrong?

I don't think so. The [large number of issues on this topic](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/search?q=modal+modal-open+event&type=Issues) suggests that this was either not well-designed, or not designed to support this. Relevant bugs would be  
[Multiple modals fix #5022](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/5022), [Multiple modals #11872](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11872) and  
[.modal-open is not applied to body when "switching" to another modal #11865](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11865) where it is explicitly said by @mdo:

> *Yup, we won't be supporting multiple modals.*

> So what to do about it?

A small timeout should definitely help:

```
currentModal.modal('hide').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (){
    setTimeout(function() {
        nextModal.modal('show');
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Well, let's carry on. Thank you for letting me know the "community" decision about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing this in action, my guess is that there is some kind of callback handler that removes the class "modal-open". You can try manually adding it like this:

```
currentModal.modal('hide').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (){
    nextModal.modal('show');
    body.addClass('modal-open');
});
```

But instead of overriding Bootstrap, have you looked into `data-dismiss` and `data-target`?

Comment: If there is an async callback (which is my guess as well), this won't help - it executes not later than a sole `modal('show')`. A timeout might work around this.

Comment: Yeah I considered that as well, so it's better to find that function if a native-to-Bootstrap way can't be figured out.

Comment: As @Bergi said, it doesn't works. I have found a quick solution, just waiting a few moments before showing next modal. But I think Bootstrap shouldn't work this way, right?